# ASP.Net MVC : Trying to store image url in js variable using razor syntax

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

in js variable i am trying to store image url using razon syntax but getting error. here is my sample code.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   var loader = '@Url.Content("~/images/loader.gif")';
});
```

i follow this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/21486213/728750
https://stackoverflow.com/a/29798960/728750

but i follow the same syntax but in my case i am getting error.
my js code is in separate file....not in view file.

looking for suggestion. thanks

### EDIT

i have this code in my main view at top.

```
<script>
    var loaderUrl
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var loaderUrl = '@Url.Content("~/images/loader.gif")';
        alert(loaderUrl);
    });
</script>
```

later i try to access this variable `loaderUrl` in external js file which is loading at bottom of my main view......but still no luck.

Comment: What is the resulting client-side output?  What is the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use `@Url.Content("~/images/loader.gif")` in a separate JS file. This has to be added to the view. 
What can you do is to create a global JS variable set it in your view and use it in your external JS.

Add this to your view. Then use the loaderUrl in your external JS file.

```
<script>
   var loaderUrl= '@Url.Content("~/images/loader.gif")';
</script>
```

Comment: loaderUrl is getting undefined in externel js file....i  checked there by alert() function.

Comment: Make sure it's loaded before your external JS. Remove document.ready and give it a try

Comment: what do u mean by sucks?

Answer (score 4):

You can't.
Store url in hidden field value in cshtml:

```
<input type='hidden' value='@Url.Content("~/images/loader.gif")' id='loaderUrl' />
```

And in js:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   var loader = $('#loaderUrl').val();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

When you have javascript in separate file then Razor syntax won't work in JS file. What I did when I had this issue it to keep variable in `_commonJsGobal.cshtml` and declared the variables required to access from JS files.

on `_commonJsGlobal.cshtml` add below script:

```
<script>
    var ROOT = '@Url.Content("~/")';
</script>
```

Then in your JS file use it like:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   var loader = ROOT + '/images/loader.gif")';
});
```

Make sure the this partial gets rendered on required views on top of everything.

Comment: see my edit section. there i said what approach i am following.

Comment: You declared the `loaderVariable` two times. Only declare it once and out of scope of functions.